# Box2D bodies unexpected overlap

Tags: javascript, box2d, game-physics

I've recently discovered PlanckJS, a 2D JavaScript physics engine, and I wanted to control the position of an object and make it interact with other physical bodies. Push them basically.

In fact, to navigate this object (let's name it 'player') I just have a JSON with the x and y coordinates where this body have to be drawn.

So, I implemented a code that works in some cases, but in most of the cases the 'player' overlaps the other bodies. You can observe it in the image shown below.

[image]

```
var player = null;
planck.testbed('Collition', function(testbed) {
    var pl = planck, Vec2 = pl.Vec2, Math = pl.Math;
    var width = 16.00, height = 8.00;
    var BALL_R = 0.25;
    testbed.x = 0, testbed.y = 0;
    testbed.width = width * 1.2, testbed.height = height * 1.2;
    testbed.ratio = 100;
    var world = pl.World({});
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        var bot=world.createDynamicBody({linearDamping:0.1,angularDamping:0.2});
        bot.setBullet(true);
        var pos_y = (i%2)? BALL_R : 2*BALL_R;
        bot.setPosition({x: (i*2), y: pos_y});
        bot.createFixture(pl.Circle(BALL_R), {friction: 0.1,restitution: 0.99,mass:1,userData:'bot'});
    }
   player = world.createDynamicBody({mass:0});
   player.setPosition({x: -width / 4, y: 0});
   player.createFixture(pl.Circle(BALL_R), {});

   world.on('post-solve', function(contact) {
        console.log('post-solve');
        var fA = contact.getFixtureA(), bA = fA.getBody();
        var fB = contact.getFixtureB(), bB = fB.getBody();
        var bot = fA.getUserData() == botFixDef.userData && bA || fB.getUserData() == botFixDef.userData && bB;
   });
   return world;
});
var stepsData=[{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0}];
client.on('objects-update', function(objects){
    stepsData.push({x: objects[0].x*2, y: objects[0].y})
    var transformX=objects[0].x*2 - stepsData[stepsData.length-2].x;
    var transformY=objects[0].y - stepsData[stepsData.length-2].y;

    console.log({x: objects[0].x*2, y: objects[0].y});
    player.setTransform(Vec2(transformX,transformY),1);
    player.setPosition({x: objects[0].x*2, y: objects[0].y});
});
```

Comment: Consider changing the velocity instead of the position. If you want the player to be at a particular position (for example with mouse movement), then you could either connect the player to an (invisible, non-colliding) object at its desired location and connect the two with a damped spring. Moving the player explicitly (as you have done) doesn't play well with the way the Position resolution works in planck.js.